# When placing textbox on TableLayoutPanel, Dock=Fill doesn't work

Tags: c#, properties, textbox, dock, tablelayoutpanel

I have TableLayoutPanel with 3 columns and 4 rows, devided evenly (each row takes - 25%, each column takes - 33 or 34%). On some of these cells I place labels and on other textboxes. When I assign labels property Dock = Fill, labels spread and fill all their cell size. But when I do the same with textboxes, they don't fill their cells. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your textbox is probably singleline, and your cell is higher than a single line.

In this case Dock = Fill will make the textbox as wide as the cell, but the heigth remains the same as a single line.

You can change the textbox to multiline to make it fill the entire cell.

Comment: Thanks, the problem indeed was in multiline property.

Answer (score 0):

Set Multiline property to True.